# adding context menu or spinner on OPtion Menu in android

Tags: android, contextmenu, spinner, optionmenu

```
   can any body have any idea if we can add a context menu or spinner when u click on an item on Option menu?
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, that is not possible through the menu system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a invisible Spinner on your layout. When the OptionMenu is clicked, you call the peformClick on this invisible Spinner.